# Bootstrap Modals & Youtube: Autoplay and Stop on Close

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, youtube, modal-dialog

I need to be able to autoplay a youtube video when a Twitter Bootstrap modal is opened and subsequently stop that video on close.

I know this question has been asked before, but the answers I can find would lead to a LOT of javascript code for a page that contains MANY videos and I am trying to cut down on the bloat. So far I have the following working for individual videos, but the issue is that each modal and each video must have this javascript code repeated with the proper variables.

```
$('#vidThumbnail-1').click(function () {
        var src = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/8bKmrhI-YT8?&amp;autoplay=1';
        $('#vid1').modal('show');
        $('#vid1 iframe').attr('src', src);

      //Fit Vids Implamented Below for Mobile Compatibility
        $("#vid1Thumbnail-1 iframe").wrap("<div class='flex-video'/>");
        $(".flex-video").fitVids();
    });
$('#vid1 button').click(function () {
        $('#vid1 iframe').removeAttr('src');
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="vidThumbnail-1"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/8bKmrhI-YT8/0.jpg" /></div>

<div id="vid1" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/8bKmrhI-YT8" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>   
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This gets bloated when you have 20 videos and 20 modals!
Is there a way to utilize the Data Attributes method of initiating a modal built-into bootstrap rather than call it individually, while still modifying the iframe src within only the target modal? The link to open the modal would then be:

```
<a href="#vid1" role="button" data-toggle="modal">
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/8bKmrhI-YT8/0.jpg"></a>
```

Then:

1. Read the existing src attribute of the iframe in the target modal (set that to a variable?)
2. Append the existing src attribute with "&autoplay=1" to initiate the video.
3. Replace the src attribute with the original upon closing the modal (via the button specifically like it is above is fine).

This way I would not need to write script for each individual modal, saving a lot of time AND bloated JS. However, I have no idea where to start modifying the bootstrap.js to accomplish this and I'm not experienced in JS (or any) programming. Thanks for any help you can give me!

Answer (score 13):

My solution:

- do **not** add `&amp;autoplay=1` to the iframe src manually

then add this script:

```
var videoSrc = $("#myModal iframe").attr("src");

$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () { // on opening the modal
  // set the video to autostart
  $("#myModal iframe").attr("src", videoSrc+"&amp;autoplay=1");
});

$("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) { // on closing the modal
  // stop the video
  $("#myModal iframe").attr("src", null);
});
```

Comment: this causes error while playing. Use "?autoplay=1" instead of "&amp;autoplay=1"

Comment: @neelabh use "?autoplay=1" if you have no existing params on your youtube url and autoplay is the first one, otherwise use "&amp;autoplay=1" to add it as a second or more param.

Comment: this worked for me but I had to manually add allow="autoplay" to my iframe embed code

Comment: This solution worked for me greatly! But only for one video on the page... I need to have 4 modal windows and autoplay a video with four different vimeo videos on each. However when I do, only the last video on the markup loads on the modal windows, no matter which button I click. Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Hello @Benjamin Morrison Hope you got the solution already, I am answering this for other user who are still searching for same solution

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modalclick').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var src = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $('#myModal iframe').attr('src', src);
  });
  //auto close or pause on model hide
  $("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $("#myModal iframe").attr("src", '');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <iframe src="" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">SKIP >></button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a class="modalclick" href="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/3j4nia24Oms?rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1">click me</a><br>
<a class="modalclick" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ycK617mKlvA?rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1">click me 1</a><br>
<a class="modalclick" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/z329gFDUJis?rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1">click me 2</a>
```

Just Add Youtube Embed url on href tag of clickable link, you can make as many as link you link. @Benjamin in your case keep image inside anchor tag so that Image is clickable.

Comment: Above example is working fine on website, but I don't know why iframe is not loading here, copy this code , its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
                    <div class="close-button">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    </div>

   $('.close').on('click', function (e) {
        $("#myModal iframe").attr("src", null);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a dynamic way to handle this issue, so I created a dynamic way to handle this for a site that we are working on.

Here are the links:

```
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#video1">Video: video 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#video2">Video: video 2</a></li>
```

Here are the modals:

```
<div id="video1" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vidpath" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div id="video2" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vidpath2" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Here is the script:

```
// autoplay video functionality
$( "[data-target^='#video']" ).click(function() { 
    // get the ID of the clicked video
    var dataTarget = $(this).attr("data-target");
    dataTarget = dataTarget.substring(1,7); 
    var vidId = '#'+dataTarget; 

    // get the vid src
    var vidSrc = $(vidId+ " iframe").attr('src');

    // create the autoplay
    var vidSrcAuto = vidSrc+'?autoplay=1'; 

    // get the iframe element
    var iframeEl = $(vidId+ " iframe"); 


    $(vidId).on('show.bs.modal', function () {  
        $(iframeEl).attr("src", vidSrcAuto);
    });

    $(vidId).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {  
        $(iframeEl).attr("src", vidSrc);  
    });   

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mNCJs/9/).

I've added a bit of progressive enhancement so were the JS to fail you would be taken to the YouTube video in this case.

The link requires a data-video-embed and a target to where we are going to be adding the video every thing else should just work. The event in the example is for Bootstrap 3 modal if you are using 2.X it will just be 'hide'.

```
$('[data-provider="modal-video"]')
   .on('click', function (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      var $target = $(evt.currentTarget),
          videoSrc = $target.data('video-embed'),
          $modal = $($target.data('target'));

      $modal
        .find('iframe').attr('src', videoSrc)
        .end()
        .on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
            $(this)
                .off('hide.bs.modal')
                .find('iframe').attr('src', '');
        })
        .modal('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The clean way is to enable [JS Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) for embedded iframe. Just by adding `enablejsapi` parameter. As of year 2020 this was only working solution for stop video without hacks.

I end up with:

```
function play_youtube_in_modal(src) {
    // enablejsapi = for enabling to stop on hide.bs.modal
    src += "?autoplay=1&modestbranding=1&rel=0&fs=1&enablejsapi=1";
    $("#modal_youtube_iframe").attr("src", src);

    //show
    $("#modal_youtube").modal("show");
}

// stop playing the youtube video when I close the modal
$('#modal_youtube').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#modal_youtube_iframe').each(function(){
        this.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"stopVideo","args":""}', '*')
    });
})
```