# disable video autoplay in twitter bootrap and stop video when modal is closed

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, video

I'm embedding a local video to my page using Bootstrap 3

I use this code inside the modal

```
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">        
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" height="300" width="480"        
    src="hunnybunny.mp4"></iframe></div>
```

How can I prevent this video from autoplay? I also want the video to stop when the modal window is closed.

Comment: Perhaps look into the `<video>` tag and it's attributes?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Bootstrap Modals & Youtube: Autoplay and Stop on Close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755364/bootstrap-modals-youtube-autoplay-and-stop-on-close)

Answer (score 2):

I was having issues with this and found a workaround. Drop the iframe in the html, for example:
(Note: I wanted video on the left so i put it in a row in the first 7 columns, also the "class = left_vid" is defined in my "override" custom linked style sheet)

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
           <video controls class= left_vid> <source src="vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        This browser does not display this video type </video>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
           <p> Text stuff </p>
        </div>
</div>
```

In the style.css

```
.left_vid {
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width: 80%;
    height:auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to use an iframe for this? If not have look at the HTML5 video-tag:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

You are using iframe, you can not stop playing, you can only remove element like this

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $( ".embed-responsive-16" ).remove();
})
```

This is just example, we dont have all you code :(