# I need to open 4 Bootstrap modals (4.1 version) and autoplay a different Vimeo video on each one of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, vimeo

I've been using this solution by [Franceso Borzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3497671/francesco-borzi):

```
var videoSrc = $("#myModal iframe").attr("src");

$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () { // on opening the modal
  // set the video to autostart
  $("#myModal iframe").attr("src", videoSrc+"&amp;autoplay=1");
});

$("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) { // on closing the modal
  // stop the video
  $("#myModal iframe").attr("src", null);
});
```

FYI: This snippet can be found on this thread: [Bootstrap Modals & Youtube: Autoplay and Stop on Close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755364/bootstrap-modals-youtube-autoplay-and-stop-on-close/36450445#36450445):

It works when there is only one Vimeo video on the page. When I try to open a different video for each modal, the modals only play the latest video on the markup.

This is my code so far:

```
<div class="modal" data-modal-window id="modal-vimeo-01">
    <iframe id="v01" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/726139458?h=02e309cac8" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <button data-modal-close class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><i class="icofont-close-circled"></i></button>
</div>

<div class="modal" data-modal-window id="modal-vimeo-02">
    <iframe id="v02" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/723317173?h=8ce2334289" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <button data-modal-close class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><i class="icofont-close-circled"></i></button>
</div>


    <script>
    var videoSrc = $("#modal-vimeo-01 iframe").attr("src");

    $('#modal-vimeo-01').on('show.bs.modal', function () { // on opening the modal
    // set the video to autostart
    $("#modal-vimeo-01 iframe").attr("src", videoSrc+"&amp;autoplay=1");
    });

    $("#modal-vimeo-01").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) { // on closing the modal
    // stop the video
    $("#modal-vimeo-01 iframe").attr("src", null);
    });
</script>

<script>
    var videoSrc = $("#modal-vimeo-02 iframe").attr("src");

    $('#modal-vimeo-02').on('show.bs.modal', function () { // on opening the modal
    // set the video to autostart
    $("#modal-vimeo-02 iframe").attr("src", videoSrc+"&amp;autoplay=1");
    });

    $("#modal-vimeo-02").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) { // on closing the modal
    // stop the video
    $("#modal-vimeo-02 iframe").attr("src", null);
    });
</script>
```

I'm quite new to JS and Jquery, so any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You problem will be most likely that you have 4 modals/videos that have the same class or id. Since I can't see your code I can't tell you where your mistake is, but that will be the problem for sure.

You should try it with having 4 id`s for your modals (like #modal1, #modal2, etc.) and and make sure that you select the correct video source, which you do in the first line:

```
var videoSrc = $("#myModal iframe").attr("src");
```

You would need something like

```
$("#modal1 iframe")
$("#modal2 iframe")
$("#modal3 iframe")
$("#modal4 iframe")
```

If this is not helping you, then you need to post your code. Because the code you posted is fine.

**EDIT:**

You are reacreating / overriding the videoSrc variable. You need to use unique names for these.

```
var videoSrc1 = $("#modal-vimeo-01 iframe").attr("src");
var videoSrc2 = $("#modal-vimeo-02 iframe").attr("src");
var videoSrc3 = $("#modal-vimeo-03 iframe").attr("src");
var videoSrc4 = $("#modal-vimeo-04 iframe").attr("src");
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add my code. I did now (with only 2 videos, to make it shorter). But as you can see,  I did use different id's for each modal.

Comment: I just saw your edit and that fixed my problem. Thanks a lot for your time and effort. I can't believe I missed that simple thing. it's embarrassing to be honest. But well, at least it's done. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the scope of `videoSrc`

You set the value to `src` of the `iframe` of the first video

Then in the second script, you redefine `videoSrc` to be the `src` of the second `iframe`

The scope of `videoSrc` in both cases is the same.

These are equivalent:

```
- var videoSrc = “someUrl”;
- window.videoSrc = “someUrl”
```

So in your second `script`, `videoSrc` gets overwritten.

Each modal should have its own uniquely named source variable.

**Edit:** in order to handle this properly, you would do something like this:

```
var firstModalSrc = $(firstModalID iframe).attr(src)
$(firstModalID).on(…)

var secondModalSrc = $(secondModalID iframe).attr(src)
$(secondModalD).on(…)

…
```

Comment: Yea, I figured videoSrc had something to do with it. But I still don't know how to fix this. Any ideas how I should do? Thanks!

Comment: Taking another look

Comment: Yea, I ended figuring it out. I completely missed that videoSrc should have been unique for each video since the beginning. This has been a humbling experience... Thanks a lot for your time and effort.

Comment: Awesome. Glad you got it working 